# Angular2, disable button if no checkbox selected

Tags: checkbox, angular

I have multiple checkboxes and a button that has to be enabled only if at least one checkbox is selected

```
<input type="checkbox">VALUE1
<input type="checkbox">VALUE2
<input type="checkbox">VALUE3
<input type="checkbox">VALUE4
<button>Proceed</button>
```

How is this achieved using Angular2.

*P.S: found similar questions but not using Angular2.*

Comment: try this:  *ng-if="<condition>"

Answer (score 44, accepted):

One way is to use `ngModel` on each checkbox, then control the button's `disabled` property via a method that examines each checkbox model state:

```
@Component({
  template: `
    <label *ngFor="let cb of checkboxes">
      <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="cb.state">{{cb.label}}
    </label>
    <p><button [disabled]="buttonState()">button</button>
  `
})
class App {
  checkboxes = [{label: 'one'},{label: 'two'}];
  constructor() {}
  buttonState() {
    return !this.checkboxes.some(_ => _.state);
  }
}
```

<kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/71jHnZre4s3MuViBqIEb?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Appreciate the answer given. Any idea why the buttonState function is triggered multiple times? and how to avoid triggering multiple times?

Comment: Expression interpolation is done each time Angular sees fit (something has happened in the component and Angular started its change detection algorithm to update 2way bound variables)

Comment: How would you do this only if ALL checkboes is selecred?

Comment: @Harry, `return !this.checkboxes.every(_ => _.state);`

Comment: @MarkRajcok  Getting error for using this line `return !this.checkboxes.some(_ => _.state);`

Comment: my problem to this solution is that you are creating the checkboxes dynamically using ngFor and by declaring the `checkboxes` variable in typeScript. But in the problem checkboxes are created in a static way using normal html

Answer (score 9):

Use the propertie [disable] as:

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ng-model)]="disableButton1"> VALUE1
<input type="checkbox" [(ng-model)]="disableButton2"> VALUE1
<input type="checkbox" [(ng-model)]="disableButton3"> VALUE1
<input type="checkbox" [(ng-model)]="disableButton4"> VALUE1
<button type="button" [disabled]="disableButton || disableButton2">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, but although that it works, with multiple checkboxes, it ends up selecting all if one is selected

Comment: Update my example. Look now

Comment: This works perfectly in the case of a static code, but when checkboxes are being created dynamically, say using `*ng-for` perhaps only option is using a Boolean variable assigned based on the count of selected checkboxes.

Answer (score 4):

You can perform any action by using $event in change event of checkbox.

**Sample:**

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" (change)="changeEvent($event)" />
<button [disabled]="toogleBool">button</button>
```

**TS**

```
 toggleBool: boolean=true;

 changeEvent(event) {
        if (event.target.checked) {
            this.toggleBool= false;
        }
        else {
            this.toggleBool= true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced same issue in my project and i solved it.

**sample:**

**HTML**

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Select</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
        <td><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="item.chosen"></td>
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<button [disabled]="noneSelcted()">OK</button>
```

**TS**

```
import {Componnet} from '@angular/core'

@Componnet({
    selector: 'my-test',
    templateUrl: 'app/home/test.component.html'
})

export class TestComponent{
    items = [
        { name: 'user1', chosen: false},
        { name: 'user2', chosen: false},
        { name: 'user3', chosen: false},
    ];

    noneSelected(){
        return !this.items.some(item => item.chosen);
    }
}
```